# Generics required String found kotlin.String

Tags: generics, kotlin

```
class CacheEntry<T>(val value: T, val size: Long)

interface Cache<T>{
    val NO_ENTRY_FOUND : CacheEntry<T>
}

class CacheImpl<String> : Cache<String>{
    override val NO_ENTRY_FOUND =  CacheEntry<String>(value = "not_found", size = -1)
}
```

I get this error:

> Error:(12, 65) Gradle: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.String but String was expected

I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case `String` is the name of a type parameter, not the standard `String` type, so the code from the question is equivalent to:

```
class CacheImpl<T> : Cache<T> {
    override val NO_ENTRY_FOUND = CacheEntry<T>(value = "not_found", size = -1)
}
```

`CacheEntry` requires `T` for the first argument, but instead you've provided a `String`, thats why you see a compilation error. The fix is quite simple, you should just remove `String` from `CacheImpl` declaration:

```
class CacheImpl : Cache<String> {
    override val NO_ENTRY_FOUND = CacheEntry<String>(value = "not_found", size = -1)
}
```

Comment: not the first time one adds an extra `<Type>` and gets this. Can there be a warning about long generic class parameters' names?

Comment: @voddan What about a warning for generic parameter hiding a type?

Comment: @RossAllan that would be even better, but it can go wrong if you mess up with imports